# how to run SVD in python with a 1xn matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, data-analysis, svd

So i want to run an algorithm on my dataset, and the first step is the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD). I am basing it on an example i found on a book, and there they use MatLab and run SVD on this time series that has dimension 1xn. However, when I try to run it in python using the numpy.linalg.svd, this error always comes that the matrix needs to have at least 2xn dimension.

So my question is: how can I run SVD with an 1xn matrix (or a vector) without getting this error? Does anyone have an idea? It'd be very much apreciated :)

Now i know i could time stack this data matrix, but I first wanted to run it without doing this step to see what kind of eigenvalues I would get (and I know they would not accurately describe my data, but I still want to see exactly how).

Comment: just lift your array into a 2D space. ie `np.linalg.svd(vector[:,None])` should work. Or even `np.linalg.svd(vector.reshape(-1, 1))`

Comment: what exactly is the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB everything is 2d (or more).  In `numpy`, arrays may be 1d.  Keep that in mind when apply MATLAB examples to numpy.

> this error always comes that the matrix needs to have at least 2xn dimension.

What exactly do you mean by `2xn dimension`?  To most numpy users that means a shape of (2,n), as opposed to (1,n) or (n,).

When asking SO questions it's best to include actual code,and to quote the error exactly.

When I use `svd` on a 3 element list, which becomes a (3,) array:

```
In [27]: np.linalg.svd([1,2,3])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 1
----> 1 np.linalg.svd([1,2,3])

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in svd(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py:1623, in svd(a, full_matrices, compute_uv, hermitian)
   1620         s = abs(s)
   1621         return sort(s)[..., ::-1]
-> 1623 _assert_stacked_2d(a)
   1624 t, result_t = _commonType(a)
   1626 extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_svd_nonconvergence)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py:183, in _assert_stacked_2d(*arrays)
    181 for a in arrays:
    182     if a.ndim < 2:
--> 183         raise LinAlgError('%d-dimensional array given. Array must be '
    184                 'at least two-dimensional' % a.ndim)

LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional
```

`2xn dimension' is poor paraphrase of this error.

With a (1,3) argument:

```
In [28]: np.linalg.svd([[1,2,3]])
Out[28]: 
(array([[-1.]]),
 array([3.74165739]),
 array([[-0.26726124, -0.53452248, -0.80178373],
        [-0.53452248,  0.77454192, -0.33818712],
        [-0.80178373, -0.33818712,  0.49271932]]))
```

and a (3,1):

```
In [29]: np.linalg.svd([[1],[2],[3]])
Out[29]: 
(array([[ 0.26726124, -0.53452248, -0.80178373],
        [ 0.53452248,  0.77454192, -0.33818712],
        [ 0.80178373, -0.33818712,  0.49271932]]),
 array([3.74165739]),
 array([[1.]]))
```

If you already have a 1 dimensional array, `arr[:,None]` or `arr.reshape(-1,1)` will change it to (n,1) shape.